Telegram do not save pictures to gallery neither share them in Android 14
I recently flashed a custom ROM (Evolution X) based on Android 14. Now, in the Telegram app, if I press the save to gallery or share button for images, nothing happens. When I press save to gallery for videos, a pop-up confirms that it has been saved to gallery, but I cannot find it anywhere. I checked permissions in the app info setting and access to photos and videos is "always allow all".
Any suggestions?

Related on Reddit: Can't save media in Android 14.. AFAIK, Android 14 enhanced its permissions related to photo and video storage, and many apps were affected. However, AFAIK this needs the developers of the apps to fix, not something that end-users can fit.
